# Evaluation of the integral $\int\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(2e^x+3)}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate: $$\int\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(2e^x+3)}$$

Do I have to apply method of difference or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the substitution $t=e^x$, $dt=e^x\ dx=t dx$, and you get a rational integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(2e^x+3)}=\int\frac{dt}{t(t+1)(2t+3)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Setting $$t=e^x$$ then we have $$dt=tdx$$ or $$dx=\frac{dt}{t}$$ and our integral is
$$\int\frac{dt}{t(t+1)(2t+3)}$$
can you integrate it now?
the solution should be $$-\ln  \left( t+1 \right) +2/3\,\ln  \left( 2\,t+3 \right) +1/3\,\ln 
 \left( t \right) 
$$ with $t=e^x$

Comment: Perhaps add a further hint in case he gets stuck

Answer (score 2):

An easy way will be substitute $u = \frac {1}{2e^x+3} $. Then, $e^x = \frac {1/u-3}{2} $. Thus, we get, $$I = -2\int \frac {u}{(u-1)(3u-1)} \mathrm {d}u $$

Now you can use partial fraction decomposition to simplify $I $. Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad XD

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No problem.